# With fast-forward how can I figure out the change introduced?

Tags: git, merge, git-branch, atlassian-sourcetree, fast-forward

The problem is best illustrated by the following picture (red ones are my commits and blue ones are my colleagues'):

[image: fast-forward]

So we started with a common base, commit id df1b868. He merged my codes and have all the latest code at commit 9957b17. He can also see the changes introduced in each merges. But when I merged his code with fast-forward I can not figure out the changes introduced between my last commit 79dbcee and the commit 9957b17.

Clicking through each of his commits seems not an effective way. So how can I see the changes easily ? By "see" I mean which files and where in them were changed from commit 79dbcee to commit 9957b17.

Thanks!

Update:

I fast-forward his commit and push the codes to remote repo and this is what branch tree likes now. I am working on master, imac/master is my remote repo.

His commit b7b226a is obviously the latest changes I can inspect. But all the other commits he did were introduced into my branch. I want to find an easy way to figure them out. Like I said clicking through each of his commits seems not an effective way.

[image]

Comment: If FF merge is successful `imac/master` should point to the `9957b17`. It worth showing the state of the graph **after** merge.

Comment: It is successful. imac is remote repo and I have not to push to remote b/c I want to see the changes first.

Comment: So in what branch/changeset you're currently checked out? If in `master` - then the `b7b22` is there.

Comment: His changes were not just b7b22 but all the other commits. Also please see my update.

Comment: "I want to find an easy way to see them" --- you already see them in this graph :-S

Comment: Sorry man, I have to say you are not helping.

Comment: You need to ask a better question then. If you want to "see" - you open a graph and literally look on it - exactly what you've done. If you did not mean it literally - you should have used a better term or explained it additionally